# Show Entries per author and per month

Tags: channel-entries, date, count, author

Is it possible to create a table that shows a count of the entries made per author and per month. Example would be:

Author | Jan | Feb | Mar

John Doe | 5 | 8 | 4 
Mad Man | 6 | 3 | 8

Would be needed for a complete year

Any help greatly appreciated even if an add-On is needed

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it with the fantastic add-on from laisvunas called "Entries Number" available at devot:ee

For anyone with the same problem, for me the solution looked as follows:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="your_channel" parse="inward" limit="123"}    
{author}{author_id}
{exp:entries_number channel="your_channel" author_id="{author_id}"start_on="2015-01-01 00:00" stop_before="2015-01-31 23:59"}
{entries_number}
{/exp:entries_number}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```